# Why do I have delay between "createTime" and "startTime", and how to reduce the latency of a BigQuery query?

Tags: google-bigquery

When analyzing the BigQuery audit logs, I can see the 2 following fields:

- protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.createTime
- protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatistics.startTime

During working hours, I would like to guarantee that some queries triggered by Tableau are answered quite fast, to provide the best experience for our Business users.
 
That is why I would like to reduce the latency (difference between "createTime" and "startTime") as much as possible for "interactive" queries.

Currently, the delay between "createTime" and "startTime" is on average 600 ms. 
 
But it can be more than 10 seconds or even 20, which is far more than the query response time we would like to have.

What is the reason of the delay between "createTime" and "startTime"?
 
Is it due to compilation time (generation of the query plan) ?
 
Or is it due to the facts that slots on BigQuery are not available?
 
Or something else?

Does somebody has a pointer on how to reduce this latency?
 
I've looked at the BigQuery documentation but it seems to give recommendations only to decrease execution time, not this "pre" execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think few of the factors that slow down transition from PENDING (createTime) to RUNNING (startTime) state of the BQ Job are

- `Concurrent rate limit for on-demand, interactive queries` — 50 concurrent queries
  This limit is applied at the project level. To raise the limit, contact support or sales
  Or, distribute your users across multiple billing projects based on department or team or something else
  and
- Available Slots - `Maximum concurrent slots per project for on-demand pricing` — 2,000
  If you need more than 2,000 slots, consider [flat-rate pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#flat_rate_pricing)
  And, still you can spread your users across different billing projects

Comment: In the last days we have seen other queries with huge latencies (more than 70 seconds delay).

We use "flat rate pricing" and I have checked that when those queries were created, we were not hitting our 2000 slot limit. 
So there must be another explanation for the latency, no?